# multiport Weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, weblogic11g

I am using oracle 11g and web logic Application Server

I want to create multiple port listener for example

1. http://ip(192.168.10.11:8080)/applicationName/index.jsp
2. http://ip(192.168.10.11:7878)/applicationName/index.jsp

My Requirement is when i restart 1 service ,that is not affected to 2

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a network channel to your server.
For details:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/config_wls/network.html#wp1058981